# Migrate String encryption from Ruby to Java

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, des

I need to produce the same encrypted string in Java as the one built with the Ruby [encrypted_strings](https://github.com/pluginaweek/encrypted_strings/blob/master/lib/encrypted_strings/symmetric_cipher.rb) library. I've tried many different ways but my Java code keeps returning a different output, and I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Below is the ruby script that produces the desired output that I can't get right in Java.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'encrypted_strings'

data = 'Whackabad'
password = 'bAJLyifeUJUBFWdHzVbykfDmPHtLKLMzViHW9aHGmyTLD8hGYZ'

encrypted_data = data.encrypt(:symmetric, :password => password)
printf "Data: #{data}\n"
printf "Encrypted Data: #{encrypted_data}"
```

Output:

```
Data: Whackabad
Encrypted Data: AEsDXVcgh2jsTjlDgh+REg==
```

I had a look at the library, and it seems to be using `DES-EDE3-CBC` as the default algorithm for encryption. I deduce from here that I should use `DESede` or `TripleDES` algorithm and `CBC` mode. As the padding option, I'm using `PKCS5Padding` cause the library is calling `pkcs5_keyivgen`.

Below is the Java code that tries to reproduce the same output unsuccessfully.

```
package ...

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class SymmetricDESedeCipher {
    private static final String DATA = "Whackabad";
    private static final String key = "bAJLyifeUJUBFWdHzVbykfDmPHtLKLMzViHW9aHGmyTLD8hGYZ";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "DESede";
    private static final String XFORM = "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    private static byte[] iv = new byte[8];

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] inpBytes,
                                  SecretKey key, String XFORM) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(XFORM);
        IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ips);
        return cipher.doFinal(inpBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] unused) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
        DESedeKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes);
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        byte[] dataBytes = DATA.getBytes();
        byte[] encBytes = encrypt(dataBytes, secretKey, XFORM);

        System.out.println("Data: " + DATA);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + new BASE64Encoder().encode(encBytes));
    }
}
```

Output

```
Data: Whackabad
Encrypted Data: ScPTKQBsR9Ni1nJ1tsMaaQ==
```

I've seen people encrypting data from Java to be decrypted from Ruby and vice-versa with different algorithms so I think this can be achieved but I can't see what's wrong. Do you have an idea? If so, that'd be of much help!

Thanks

Comment: Start by ensuring you're using the same bytes. String representations vary widely between languages.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to use that ruby encryption library? The documentation seems to indicate it derives the Initialization Vector from a password, which is a terrible idea -- [IV's should be random](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/82)

Comment: Yes @dnault, it's legacy what I'm trying to translate into Java so that method is the one in use at this moment and the one I want to replicate.

Comment: @chrylis I'm not sure which string representation is Ruby using so I can't reproduce it in Java. If you know, that would be of help too.

Comment: If you want bug-for-bug compatibility, I would investigate how the ruby library derives the IV and then do the same thing in Java (instead of using an all-zero IV as your code does now).

Comment: 3DES (an algorithm past it's prime) takes a 24 byte key, you are supplying a 50 character string, that is not correct.

Comment: @zaph you are right as I was using a password as a key in my Java code. I found my way to get the key and iv from the password so thanks for driving me into the solution

Comment: Thanks! @dnault Your comment helped to end up with a solution to what I was trying to achieve

Comment: So what was the solution? :-) Please post it as an "answer" so it is more visible to help the next guy.

Comment: @leigh I just posted that. Hope it helps someone

Comment: @rakemous - Great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to [derive the IV and key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420098/how-to-extract-the-iv-vector-generated-by-encrypt-method-from-encrypted-strings) from the given password.

From the link above, you will get an encoded IV and KEY that corresponds with `"VDiJjncs4ak="` and `"s9e42J3PpmQv8n5T8L3zzuFaGdrzK/wU"` respectively.
This means that the key and IV vector used in the Java code are wrong as it was said in the comments.

Below is the resulting Java code:

```
public class SymmetricDESedeCipher {
    private static final String DATA = "Whackabad";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "DESede";
    private static final String XFORM = "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String KEY = "s9e42J3PpmQv8n5T8L3zzuFaGdrzK/wU";
    private static final String IV = "VDiJjncs4ak=";

    private static byte[] encrypt(String data,
                                  SecretKey key, String XFORM, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(XFORM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    }

    public static void main(String[] unused) throws Exception {
        DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(KEY));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec);

        byte[] encBytes = encrypt(DATA, secretKey, XFORM,  new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(IV));

        System.out.println("Data: " + DATA);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Data: " + new BASE64Encoder().encode(encBytes));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Data: Whackabad
Encrypted Data: AEsDXVcgh2jsTjlDgh+REg==
```