# How to use Ruby to decrypt plaintext that was encrypted with the openssl command line utility using a password and no salt?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I have encrypted some plaintext using the `openssl` command line utility using a password:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl enc -e -base64 -rc4 -nosalt -pass pass:secretkey
```

This returns:

```
ryW2
```

How can I decrypt this value using Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Finally with reference of Above in Ruby

### Encode

```
def encrypt(str, key)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('RC4')
  cipher.key = OpenSSL::Digest.digest('md5', key)
  cipher.decrypt
  Base64.encode64(cipher.update(str) + cipher.final)
end

encrypt('This is Test', 'Test')
=> "JGmpM+ewGA79qaZH\n"
```

### Decode

```
def decrypt(encrypted_string, key)
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('RC4')
  decipher.key = OpenSSL::Digest.digest('md5', key)
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.update(Base64.decode64(encrypted_string)) + decipher.final
end

decrypt("JGmpM+ewGA79qaZH\n", "Test")
=> "This is Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command you would need to enter to encrypt the string `foo` into some ciphertext:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl enc -e -base64 -rc4 -nosalt -pass pass:secretkey -p
```

And this returns:

```
key=610A2EE688CDA9E724885E23CD2CFDEE
ryW2
```

`ryW2` is your base64 encoded ciphertext.

We have added `-p` so we can see the key that is used for encryption.

`-p` is required because OpenSSL uses an internal function `EVP_BytesToKey` to convert the passphrase to a key and there is no equivalent Ruby method to do this. Accordingly, you'll have to use this key value directly in Ruby when encrypting or decrypting instead of the passphrase.

Decryption is just as straight-forward:

```
echo "ryW2" | openssl enc -d -base64 -rc4 -nosalt -pass pass:secretkey
```

This returns:

```
foo
```

Given all this, here is how you would encrypt this string using Ruby to get the same value:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

plaintext = 'foo'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('rc4')
cipher.encrypt
# Use the key that was generated by EVP_BytesToKey
key = '610A2EE688CDA9E724885E23CD2CFDEE'
# Convert the key to a byte string
key_bytes = key.scan(/../).map { |x| x.hex.chr }.join
cipher.key = key_bytes
ciphertext = cipher.update(plaintext) + cipher.final
base64 = Base64.strict_encode64(ciphertext)
```

This returns the same value as OpenSSL on the command line:

```
ryW2
```

Decryption is fairly straightforward:

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('rc4')
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key_bytes
decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext) + decipher.final
```

This returns the original plaintext:

```
foo
```

Ultimately, encryption and decryption is fairly straightforward as long as you know what `EVP_BytesToKey` will return for a given `pass`. You can read more about `EVP_BytesToKey` here:

- [How to extract the IV vector generated by encrypt method from encrypted_strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42422932/3784008)
- [How do I refactor OpenSSL pkcs5_keyivgen in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17882919/3784008)
- https://github.com/crypto-browserify/EVP_BytesToKey
- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_BytesToKey.html

Comment: Thanks Actually it works, I was confuse in part of key_bytes

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't happy that there is no built-in way to do this in Ruby. [My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886318/3784008) to this question is a functional workaround but it requires some time-consuming steps that I'm not crazy about. So I wrote a gem called [evp_bytes_to_key](https://github.com/anothermh/evp_bytes_to_key) that'll do it for you!

First install the gem:

```
gem install evp_bytes_to_key
```

Then generate your ciphertext:

```
echo -n "foo" | openssl enc -e -base64 -rc4 -nosalt -pass pass:secretkey
```

This returns:

```
ryW2
```

Then decrypt it in Ruby:

```
require 'evp_bytes_to_key'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('rc4')
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = EvpBytesToKey::Key.new('secretkey', nil, 128, 0).key
ciphertext = Base64.strict_decode64('ryW2')
plaintext = decipher.update(ciphertext) + decipher.final
```

This returns the original plaintext:

```
foo
```

More examples for using this gem can be found in the [README](https://github.com/anothermh/evp_bytes_to_key/blob/master/README.md).